# Как запустить tomcat intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea, веб-сервер, tomcat

**Привет) Не могу запустить tomcat (ну совсем никак) в идее.**

Просто, чтобы отображало мои странички и работали сервлеты, мне не нужен war. Я нажимала fix (1й скрин) выбирала пустой варник; выбирала вар из моей папочки веб - подскажите пожалуйста, что натыкать, чтобы оно, наконец, заработало? второй день не могу запустить
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Стек:

```
"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin\catalina.bat" run
[2020-10-14 06:07:59,906] Artifact unnamed: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\Ђ­ бв бЁп\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.2\tomcat\Unnamed_medicines_5"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Users\Ђ­ бв бЁп\.jdks\corretto-11.0.8"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Using CATALINA_OPTS:   ""
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
14-Oct-2020 18:08:01.361 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.39
14-Oct-2020 18:08:01.368 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Oct 6 2020 14:11:46 UTC
14-Oct-2020 18:08:01.368 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.39.0
14-Oct-2020 18:08:01.368 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
14-Oct-2020 18:08:01.368 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
14-Oct-2020 18:08:01.369 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
14-Oct-2020 18:08:01.369 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Users\РђРЅР°СЃС‚Р°СЃРёСЏ\.jdks\corretto-11.0.8
14-Oct-2020 18:08:01.369 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           11.0.8+10-LTS
14-Oct-2020 18:08:01.370 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Amazon.com Inc.
14-Oct-2020 18:08:01.370 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\РђРЅР°СЃС‚Р°СЃРёСЏ\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.2\tomcat\Unnamed_medicines_5
14-Oct-2020 18:08:01.370 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
14-Oct-2020 18:08:01.376 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
14-Oct-2020 18:08:01.377 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
14-Oct-2020 18:08:01.377 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
14-Oct-2020 18:08:01.377 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\РђРЅР°СЃС‚Р°СЃРёСЏ\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.2\tomcat\Unnamed_medicines_5\conf\logging.properties
14-Oct-2020 18:08:01.378 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
14-Oct-2020 18:08:01.378 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
14-Oct-2020 18:08:01.379 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
14-Oct-2020 18:08:01.379 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
14-Oct-2020 18:08:01.379 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=C:\Users\РђРЅР°СЃС‚Р°СЃРёСЏ\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.2\tomcat\Unnamed_medicines_5\jmxremote.password
14-Oct-2020 18:08:01.379 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=C:\Users\РђРЅР°СЃС‚Р°СЃРёСЏ\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.2\tomcat\Unnamed_medicines_5\jmxremote.access
14-Oct-2020 18:08:01.380 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
14-Oct-2020 18:08:01.380 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
14-Oct-2020 18:08:01.381 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
14-Oct-2020 18:08:01.381 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
14-Oct-2020 18:08:01.381 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\РђРЅР°СЃС‚Р°СЃРёСЏ\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.2\tomcat\Unnamed_medicines_5
14-Oct-2020 18:08:01.382 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
14-Oct-2020 18:08:01.382 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\temp
14-Oct-2020 18:08:01.388 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Users\РђРЅР°СЃС‚Р°СЃРёСЏ\.jdks\corretto-11.0.8\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;$JAVA_HOME\bin\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\;C:\Users\РђРЅР°СЃС‚Р°СЃРёСЏ\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.3\bin;;.]
14-Oct-2020 18:08:01.817 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
14-Oct-2020 18:08:01.880 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [848] milliseconds
14-Oct-2020 18:08:01.966 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
14-Oct-2020 18:08:01.966 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.39]
14-Oct-2020 18:08:01.982 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
14-Oct-2020 18:08:02.000 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [115] milliseconds
Connected to server
[2020-10-14 06:08:02,012] Artifact unnamed: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[2020-10-14 06:08:02,098] Artifact unnamed: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2020-10-14 06:08:02,099] Artifact unnamed: com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JmxAdminException: com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: C:\Users\Анастасия\Desktop\medicines\out\artifacts\unnamed not found for the web module.
[2020-10-14 06:08:07,879] Artifact unnamed: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[2020-10-14 06:08:07,894] Artifact unnamed: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2020-10-14 06:08:07,895] Artifact unnamed: com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JmxAdminException: com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: C:\Users\Анастасия\Desktop\medicines\out\artifacts\unnamed not found for the web module.
14-Oct-2020 18:08:12.242 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory РЈСЃС‚Р°РЅРѕРІРєР° РІРµР± РїСЂРёР»РѕР¶РµРЅРёСЏ РІ РїР°РїРєСѓ [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\manager]
14-Oct-2020 18:08:13.007 WARNING [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [266] milliseconds.
14-Oct-2020 18:08:13.050 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\manager] has finished in [808] ms
"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin\catalina.bat" stop
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\Ђ­ бв бЁп\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.2\tomcat\Unnamed_medicines_5"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Users\Ђ­ бв бЁп\.jdks\corretto-11.0.8"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Using CATALINA_OPTS:   ""
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
14-Oct-2020 18:08:24.656 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer No shutdown port configured. Shut down server through OS signal. Server not shut down.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы указываете `WAR` файл в настройках, но никакого `WAR` у вас в структуре проекта нет (видно на скриншотах), что, собственно, вы и получаете в ошибках.

> Просто, чтобы отображало мои странички и работали сервлеты, мне не нужен war

Как раз `WAR` вам и нужен, иначе что вы собираетесь разворачивать в `Tomcat`? Сперва вы создаете приложение, потом собираете его в `WAR` и именно этот `WAR` разворачиваете в `Tomcat`-е.